# Prevent FloatDomainError NaN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

In this calculation:

```
months = (saved_cents / spend_cents).to_f.floor
```

I get the following error:

```
FloatDomainError: NaN
```

I think `saved_cents` and `spend_cents` are floats, that's why I don't understand why I get this error.

**What could be the reason for this error? And how can I fix it?**

Comment: `to_f` is superfluous if both, `saved_cents` and `spend_cents` are floats, because `Float#/` always returns a float.

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation, a [`FloatDomainError`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/FloatDomainError.html) is:

> Raised when attempting to convert special float values (in particular `Infinity` or `NaN`) to numerical classes which don't support them.

In your code, a `FloatDomainError` occurs when both values are zero:

```
saved_cents = 0.0
spend_cents = 0.0

(saved_cents / spend_cents).floor
#=> FloatDomainError: NaN
```

Because zero divided by zero is `NaN`:

```
saved_cents / spend_cents
#=> NaN
```

and although `NaN` is a float, attempting to send it a `floor` message results in that error:

```
Float::NaN.floor
#=> FloatDomainError: NaN
```

> What could be the reason for this error? And how can I fix it?

Double check your input. Maybe there's another bug which sets the values to `0.0` accidentally.